# Format (same) line to different styles between specific marker points

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Have been struggling with something that should be pretty straightforward.  I have a line chart showing sports teams attendances over a number of seasons.  This is easy to do, except I want to format the line to a dash when a team is relegated to the division below e.g. division 1 normal line, division 2 dash.  An example that someone else has created (unfortunately not in Plotly) can be viewed [here](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_regions.html).

So far the best I have managed is by setting two variables for a team - one for division 1 (tier 1), one for division 2 - to appear as separate variables, which would be OK but for the large gap that appears - see [Link to attendanceDiv chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8A4K.png).

Would appreciate any help with this.  Should really be an option to format lines between markers using selectedpoints.  Code below.  Thanks.

```
var bristol1 = {
x: ['2000-01', '2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04', '2004-05'],
y: [4639, 5316, 7023, null, null],
name: 'Bristol (tier 1)',
mode: 'lines+markers',
line: {
  color: 'blue',
  width: 2
  }
};

var bristol2 = {
x: ['2000-01', '2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04', '2004-05'],
y: [null, null, null, 3684, 5234],
name: 'Bristol (tier 2)',
mode: 'lines+markers',
line: {
  color: 'blue',
  width: 2,
  dash: 'dash'
  }
};

var data = [bristol1, bristol2];

var layout = {
  title: 'First Tier Rugby Union Clubs: Average Attendance',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Season',
    type: 'category',
    tickvals: ['2000-01', '2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04', '2004-05']
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Attendance',
    range: [0, 8000]
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('attendanceDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```